# What algorithm does PGP use to encrypt email?

Tags: rsa, pgp, dsa

I know it uses RSA/DSA to create keys, but does it use that same algorithm for the actual cipher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [How PGP Works](http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/#p10) it uses a hybrid approach that generates a secret key for symmetric encryption.  The wikipedia page for [GPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard#Process) then indicates that CAST5, Camellia, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, and Twofish are the supported ciphers.

Comment: I wouldn't point to pgpi.org. It's over a decade out of date and not maintained.

But great answer. -- Jon